# I can't reinstall symfony2

Tags: symfony, php

I am using symfony2 standard version, on linux mint 12.

I created a symfony2 project 2 days and everything went well, i installed a wrong bundle and messed up the project so i decided to delete the `Symfony` folder, and reinstall symfony.

And now, if i do `php app/check.php` i get the timezone error, although my timezone is set correctly, and the configuration page looks like this

[image]

i tried

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
```

and i tried

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs
```

could not fix it

**Edit**

`php bin/vendors install --reinstall` fixed the issue (Hakan Deryal thank you sir). However, I found out that if you rename the `Symfony` folder to `symfony` or any other name, you'll get the error, or everything goes normal but when you press `Configure your Symfony Application online` you'll get this error

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/mysite/web/app_dev.php/_configurator/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

So my next question is how to change of the symfony2 project , say you have 2 symfony2 project on localhost, they can't have the same name

Comment: Do that directories even exist?

Comment: @zerkms yes there are empty folders called `cache` and `logs` inside the `app` folder

Comment: Btw, `php bin/vendors install --reinstall`

Comment: @HakanDeryal please read my edit

Comment: Well, I haven't had any problems with changing the directory name. Can't think of any reason why that would cause any problems right now.

Comment: @HakanDeryal actually if i rename the folder, i get either the error described, or everything goes normal but when i press `Configure your Symfony Application online` i get this error `Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/mysitel/web/app_dev.php/_configurator/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`

Answer (score 1):

Hi some time just clearing cache is not enough.

Event I came across the same type of problem, after clearing the cache, try to rebuild it.

commands are:

```
$ sudo php app/console cache:clear 
$ sudo php app/console cache:warmup
$ sudo chmod 777 -R app/cache app/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set permission is to use ACLs:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

You could also try a `chown www-data app/logs`

Symfony reinstall at this point is not very relevant

Comment: please read my edit, and thank you for telling me about ACLs, I use these commands to set permissions from now on :)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your second problem. However if you want to use multiple SF projects in localhost, simple use sub-demain and vHost config